# handling modular web-application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, module

i know this is pretty general, but i couldnt find any suited information regarding this topic:
we need to develop a module-based system (ASP.NET-MVC) that should be adaptable for multiple different customers. Each of the modules can be customized for every company.

1. Is there some kind of tutorial on how to handle such complex requirements? (multiple customers that can have different compositions of modules and different module-implementations)
2. Can you recommend an approach on how to represent this structure in TFS?
3. How can the enrollment be done when each customer can have a different composition of modules.
4. Is there a recommended tool to keep track of all the versions that are enrolled on the different servers (staging, customers, ...)?

Would be really glad if someone could shed some light on that topic or at least throw some hints on what to exactly search for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am not sure if there is any tutorials but MVC its like a Class lib with views.
2. You can devide to components lets say you have module called payment, this module will include controllers, scripts, and views. To use this module you can have 2 options, 1. [Create nuGet package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) with all content. Other option is to create zip file with content and just copy all to your project.
3. To use it for each customer would be simple since you divide all to different modules, and then you can include or exclude from your project.
4. As i mentioned i would use private Nuget server to handle packages then its really easy to add remove components just with few click. Also you can add build server where you can run unittests and if everything passed sucessfully then publish new nuget package

Comment: @r3try i am not sure. I will try to do that on holidays with some examples.

Comment: thank you for your help. i managed to use nuget-packages for my 'modules' and those are then combined in my main-application as areas (thx for the hint). Any further guidance is much appreciated :)